# Vala read file line by line

Tags: java, file-io, io

```
int n = sc.nextInt();
char[][] original = new char[n][n];
char [][] result = new char[n][n];
String line;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  line = sc.nextLine();
  System.out.println(line);
  for (int u = 0; u < n; u++) {
    original[i][u] = line.charAt(u);
  }
}

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  line = sc.nextLine();
  for (int u = 0; u < n; u++) {
    result[i][u] = line.charAt(u);
  }
}
```

I have a file that looks like this:

```
2
ha
ah
lo
ol
```

I have an integer N on firs line, and then two N*N matrixes of characters.

I am trying to read them to two arrays of arrays of chars, but I get this error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:695)
    at transform.main(transform.java:25)

Line 25 is this:

```
original[i][u] = line.charAt(u);
```

I just don't get it, I think I'm doing everything just fine. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: What is the line content that is last printed before the error?

Comment: Why are you mentioning [Vala](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vala_(programming_language)) in the title when this is about Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose your `sc` is a scanner instance? The method `nextInt()` does read the next number from your file but does *not* process the following newline. Thus, your first call to `nextLine()` will return just an empty string (i.e. all characters until the newline which was not processed yet). You will see that you `println(...)` call does print an empty line. You may insert a call to `newLine()` before your loop to fix this behavior.